# How can I replace comma separated ids in a string by doing a lookup in json response in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to replace the ids in the following string by values which are in json.

```
target_country ="214,216,278,418"
```

Here is the json with the values

```
{
   "data": [
            {
              "label": "BE",
              "id": 214
            },
            {
              "label": "CH",
              "id": 215
            },
            {
              "label": "DE",
              "id": 274
            },
            {
              "label": "ES",
              "id": 216
            },
            {
              "label": "EU",
              "id": 416
            },
            {
              "label": "GB",
              "id": 218
            },
            {
              "label": "HR",
              "id": 278
            },
            {
              "label": "US",
              "id": 418
            }
          ]
         }
```

I want the result to be

```
target_country = 'BE, ES, HR, US'
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: A good way would be to create a dictionary of `id` to `label` mappings. Then use that to replace each id in `target_country` with the label

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) with [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dealfields)
>>> df
    id label
0  214    BE
1  215    CH
2  274    DE
3  216    ES
4  416    EU
5  218    GB
6  278    HR
7  418    US
>>> data = [{

  "target_country": "214,216,278,418"
}]
>>> fields = df[df['id'].isin(map(int,data[0]["target_country"].split(',')))
                ]['label'].tolist()
>>> target_country = ', '.join(fields)
>>> target_country
'BE, ES, HR, US'
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create a dictionary from your list of dicts,

```
lst = [{'label': 'BE', 'id': 214},
 {'label': 'CH', 'id': 215},
 {'label': 'DE', 'id': 274},
 {'label': 'ES', 'id': 216},
 {'label': 'EU', 'id': 416},
 {'label': 'GB', 'id': 218},
 {'label': 'HR', 'id': 278},
 {'label': 'US', 'id': 418}]

dct = {str(x['id']):x['label'] for x in lst}

>>>print(dct)
{'214': 'BE',
 '215': 'CH',
 '274': 'DE',
 '216': 'ES',
 '416': 'EU',
 '218': 'GB',
 '278': 'HR',
 '418': 'US'}
```

then use list comprehension to convert you string,

```
data=[{"target_country": "214,216,278,418"}]
for item in data:
    if item.get('target_country',None):
        item['target_country']=','.join([dct.get(y) for y in item['target_country'].split(',')])

>>>data
[{'target_country': 'BE,ES,HR,US'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dict with the JSON data:

```
d = {
"data": [
    {
        "label": "BE",
        "id": 214
    },
    {
        "label": "CH",
        "id": 215
    },
    {
        "label": "DE",
        "id": 274
    },
    {
        "label": "ES",
        "id": 216
    },
    {
        "label": "EU",
        "id": 416
    },
    {
        "label": "GB",
        "id": 218
    },
    {
        "label": "HR",
        "id": 278
    },
    {
        "label": "US",
        "id": 418
    }
]
}
```

then the following code should work:

```
result = [s["label"] for s in d['data'] if str(s["id"]) in target_country]
```

This loops through the "data" list inside your dictionary, then extracts the label for each entry that matches the `str(s["id"]) in target_country`.

```
>> print(result)
>> ['BE', 'ES', 'HR', 'US']
```